# Mobile apps to track how much time a user spend using different apps on a mobile phone

Tags: android, ios, time-management, productivity

The idea is similar to the social networking site [Wakoopa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakoopa), which was a software usage tracking tool for the desktop but has since been closed. [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) is another time tracking software for desktop, which is less social-oriented, but more detailed.

What I'm looking for is a mobile app (iOS and/or Android) that runs in the background, monitoring the application usage on my mobile phone.

For Android, [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4092/3041) is a related question, but I'm not interested in tracking clicks or key strokes.

**Key features**

- Log the foreground app usage. For instance, it logs that I have used Snapchat in foreground from `14:00:00 to 14:07:12`, Chrome browser from `14:07:43 - 14:12:42` etc.
- Generate basic reports for time used by each application, which can be accessible either from cloud or local files (`.xml`, `.csv`, `.db`, etc.)

**Extra features I can think of**

- Log background applications as well (time started, time terminated, etc.)
- Generate detailed reports per application, per day, etc.
- Provide web user interface to access data in the cloud
- Social (like Wakoopa)
- Reasonable price

Answer (score 3):

[Rescue time](https://www.rescuetime.com) meets the following requirements:

- Logs foreground app usage (and also time spent on websites).
- Generates detailed reports by app, time period etc.
- Data can be accessed on the web (via your account) as well as on your phone.
- There is a premium version but all the above features are free.

Comment: On mobile it runs only on Android, np iOS unfortunately.